# Filter function dplyr seems to be not working

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr

Let's presume I have a data.fram called exprCore1 loaded in R-Studio, the df looks like this:

```
   measure qid value
1   p5      1   0.2
2   p100    1   0.8
3   map     1   0.22
4   p5      2   0.4
5   p100    2   0.5
6   map     2   0.32
```

Basically all want is every column in which the measurement method is "map".

I tried different approaches, all of them just return only a 0x4 tibble without content.

What I tried so far:

```
library("dplyr", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.4")
exprCore1MapOverall <- dplyr::filter(exprCore1, measure == "map")
```

This just returns:

```
# A tibble: 0 x 4
# ... with 4 variables: measure <chr>, queryID <chr>, value <dbl>, coreTag <chr>
```

What am I missing here? Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Edit:

Also tried

```
exprCore1MapOverall <-filter(exprCore1, measure %in%c("map"))
```

Edit2:

I cant post the whole data.frame, way to much data. I shrunk it using

```
exprCore1Fixed <- exprCore1[-c(30: 142082),]
```

Here is the dput of exprCore1Fixed

```
structure(list(measure = c("num_ret        ", "num_rel        ", 
"num_rel_ret    ", "map            ", "R-prec         ", "bpref          ", 
"recip_rank     ", "ircl_prn.0.00  ", "ircl_prn.0.10  ", "ircl_prn.0.20  ", 
"ircl_prn.0.30  ", "ircl_prn.0.40  ", "ircl_prn.0.50  ", "ircl_prn.0.60  ", 
"ircl_prn.0.70  ", "ircl_prn.0.80  ", "ircl_prn.0.90  ", "ircl_prn.1.00  ", 
"P5             ", "P10            ", "P15            ", "P20            ", 
"P30            ", "P100           ", "P200           ", "P500           ", 
"P1000          ", "num_ret        ", "num_rel        ", "ircl_prn.0.70  ", 
"ircl_prn.0.80  ", "ircl_prn.0.90  ", "ircl_prn.1.00  ", "P5             ", 
"P10            ", "P15            ", "P20            ", "P30            ", 
"P100           ", "P200           ", "P500           ", "P1000          "
), queryID = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "all", "all", "all", "all", "all", 
"all", "all", "all", "all", "all", "all", "all", "all"), value = c(752, 
5, 4, 0.1089, 0.2, 0.8, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.1429, 0.1429, 
0.1429, 0.1429, 0.0342, 0.0342, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0667, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.03, 0.02, 0.008, 0.004, 2, 3, 0.0696, 0.0565, 0.0374, 
0.0345, 0.25, 0.1962, 0.1718, 0.151, 0.1192, 0.0525, 0.0335, 
0.0164, 0.0097), coreTag = c("Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", 
"Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", 
"Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", 
"Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", 
"Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", 
"Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1", 
"Core_1", "Core_1", "Core_1")), .Names = c("measure", "queryID", 
"value", "coreTag"), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I can't replicate this issue. Your code works fine for me. By the suspicious way your `measure` column is printing, are you sure you don't have trailing or leading whitespace in the values? Like `"  map"`? Try `dplyr::filter(exprCore1, trimws(measure) == "map")` and see if you get a different result.

Comment: This code looks fine to me as well. Run `dput(exprCore1)` in your console and edit the resulting output into your post so we can use the exact same data you are using.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you do need to import the `filter` command from dplyr as you have already called `library(dplyr)`. There's no need to go `dplyr::filter(...)` in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Using

```
dplyr::filter(exprCore1, trimws(measure) == "map")
```

did the trick, thank you very much.

Comment: I would recommend trimming the whitespace for the column as part of the data setup process, before you start trying any analysis, like: `exprCore1 <- exprCore1 %>% mutate(measure = trimws(measure))`

Comment: Thank you, will take that in mind aswell.